# Angular2 cant find socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io

I was trying to listening socket event in an angular2 application.
From server side I am emitting an event and then trying to catch it from client.

app.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!', id: socket.id });
});
```

From client side I can successfully listen it from 
index.html:

```
<script src='node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js'></script>

<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('welcome', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

Till now this is OKAY. But when I try to listen this event in one of my angular component let say myComponent.ts like below:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client'
...
...
constructor(...) {
   this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
   this.socket.on('welcome', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   });
}
```

Browser says it cant find **socket.io-client**. And got some error in browser console like that:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:126 GET http://localhost:3001/socket.io-client/ 404 (Not Found)
angular2-polyfills.js:390 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3001/socket.io-client(…)
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove the import in the component? (I expect it to open the websocket but give a type error)

Comment: @echonax, you are right. It opens the socket but don't show any type error. And also no event received.

Comment: Hmm if there's an event, I was expecting it to be seen if the component is being initialized tbh.

Comment: So do you know how to solve this problem @echonax?

Comment: No, I was just trying to get more information about the problem